# PostgreSQL SSD vs HDD - why is there no difference in insert performance?

Tags: postgresql, ssd

I have a PostgreSQL12 on Ubuntu 20.04 with following tablespaces:

[image]

The default uses a HDD and there is also another tablespace on an SSD.

Then I run a test to see the differences in insert/update speed for tables placed in different tablespaces:

```
create table test_hdd
(v int);

create table test_ssd
(v int)
tablespace ssd1;

insert into test_hdd
select * from generate_series(1, 10000000); --~10sec

insert into test_ssd
select * from generate_series(1, 10000000); --~10sec


update test_hdd set v = 1; --~25sec
update test_ssd set v = 1; --~25sec
```

The expected outcome is that the operations on table `test_ssd` should be faster, but that is not the case. All the operations on both tables take almost exactly the same amount of time to complete.

**My question is: why? How do I get a write speed boost from using an SSD?**

*Bonus:*

I compared the disk write speed using `dd` to make sure that the disk for /dev is faster than the HDD disk, and it indeed is. The HDD write speed was around 224 MB/s, and for SSD it was around 1.3 GB/s.

Comment: Insert performance is mostly dependent on how fast you can flush the WAL buffer; did you move WAL segments for your tests?

Comment: I will try to move WAL directory to an SSD disk and then check performance again

Comment: Also, `generate_series` may write temp files. Put `temp_tablespaces` on the SSD.

Comment: I moved entire postgres DATA_DIR to an SSD, so now WAL data and temp tables will be written there. I made a separate tablespace on HDD. I ran the same tests as I did before and still the insert and update performance is comparable for both tablespaces

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect disk to be the bottleneck for this task on a reasonable machine.  All writes but one (the final commit) should be either buffered, or done in the background.  The bottleneck would be CPU.

If each row was inserted in a separate transaction and your HDD lacks a non-volatile write cache and your system is configured properly for durability, then having WAL on the SSD rather than HDD should be a lot faster due to the fsync speed.

Even with your single-statement INSERT, if you increased the size to the point that the temp files used for generate_series actually had to reach disk and be evicted from RAM, and then be read back in, that could also highlight the difference between SSD AND HDD.

Comment: I read some articles about using SSD tablespaces for heavy write loads, so I assumed there would be some kind of a difference? Maybe I need to test it on bigger data? Or does it really not matter if I use SSD or HDD?